# After serializing/deserializing two Lists, List.Remove won't remove any items

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, serialization

When my Windows Phone 7 game is tombstoned during gameplay, I serialize the necessary elements so when they come back to the game it can deserialize the saved data and the user can continue where they left off.
I have a List of questions (questionList) and a List of board pieces (boardPieces). These both get serialized/deserialized when navigating away from my game and that all seems to work just fine. When you answer a question, that question is removed from the list:

```
questionList.Remove(boardPiece.Question);
```

This works just fine until I tombstone my game and navigate back to it (after the List's are serialized/deserialized). Then my questionList.Remove... fails to works properly. I checked the data through breakpoints and questionList DOES appear to have a matching item but trying to remove it via List.Remove just silently fails and doesn't remove the item.

I found a workaround by looping through questionList, searching for a matching boardPiece and then removing it via the index (RemoveAt) instead of just using Remove. It doesn't seem to have much of a performance impact since I only have 16 questions at most, but I'd like to know why Remove fails after I deserialize the data so I learn something at least. Mismatching hash or something? I have no idea... :(

Here is how I serialize the questionList (it works the same for the boardPieces):

```
XmlSerializer questionListSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuestionHelper));
writer.WriteStartElement("QuestionList");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Count", questionList.Count.ToString());
foreach (QuestionHelper question in questionList)
    questionListSerializer.Serialize(writer, question);
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

and here is how it gets deserialized (same idea for boardPieces again):

```
XmlSerializer questionListSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuestionHelper));
int questionListCount = int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("Count"));
reader.Read();
for (int i = 0; i < questionListCount; i++)
    questionList.Add(questionListSerializer.Deserialize(reader) as QuestionHelper);
if (questionListCount > 0)
    reader.Read();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` is a tree serializer; if the same object is found twice in the graph, it will be serialized twice. When deserializing, this is then **two separate** objects that happen to look alike. Since `Remove` etc uses equality, which defaults to reference-equality, this is probably the issue, i.e. for that object deserialized, the two occurrences are **not** the same reference any more. Hence not found.

Options:

- except when declaring actual data, only serialize the id/key - not the object; fixup after deserialization
- use a serializer that can support object references (not `XmlSerializer`)

Comment: 3/ Override the Equals method of QuestionHelper

Comment: @KooKiz you should never override `Equals()` without also overriding `GetHashCode()`; and that still represents a different final scenario to how the OP started. For example, should `obj.Foo = "new foo";` update both references? or just one? Your suggestion, while valid, represents a functional change to how the system works.

Comment: I tried switching over to DataContractSerializer and marked the 2 classes I was serializing as '[DataContract(IsReference=true)]' but that had the same results as above. Can you explain option 1 in a little more detail so I can give that option a go? Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff DCS is also a tree serializer, unless you use the constructor overload that enables full-graph support

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. The overload isn't available in WP7 but you should still be able to enable `PreserveObjectRefrences` as shown in this example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/5a5cd6f8-f234-44ee-9861-09a999c66523. Simply adding `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` to my class doesn't seem to have any affect and I have the same behavior has before though. When I create a DCS using the `DCS(Type)` constructor, `PreserveObjectRefrences` is set to `false` so I'm not sure if I'm creating it wrong...

Comment: @Jeff if it helps, protobuf-net can be configured to support object references, and can work on WP, IIRC